# Trouble moving tasks from build.gradle into separate .gradle file be reapplied

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, apache-commons

Running into problems extracting tasks from a `build.gradle` file to then be applied, back into the app/root `build.gradle` file. The compiler can resolve `MarkupBuilder` and `JsonSlurper` fine but cannot resolve the following: `import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`.

I've tried adding it as a dependency within the newly created script and also within the app and project levels.

`'org.apache.commons.lang:commons-lang:3.5'`

The error is below

```
Could not compile script '/project/app/newscript.gradle'.
 startup failed:
 > script '/project/app/newscript.gradle': 18: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
   @ line 18, column 1.
     import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
     ^

  1 error
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible? Would I need to include the script in a different way than `apply script: newscript.gradle` or another plugin within the `newscript.gradle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Gradle script is basically a Groovy file. Which in turn gets compiled into JVM bytecode, similar to Java classes. So when compiling a script with an import, the imported classes must be on the classpath. Some classes like the MarkupBuilder are available by default (included either by Groovy or Gradle).

You have to add something like this to be able to use the classes in your script:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.commons.lang:commons-lang:3.5'
    }
}
```

The buildscript closure will add the library on the classpath of the Gradle script and you should be able to use its classes.